# how to use stop/break in for loop when a if condition is satisfied only once.( do not check after that point) using R

Tags: r

my data is like

temp- 1, 1.5, 0, 1.2, 1.3, 1.5, 1.5, 1.7, 1.5, 1.6, 1.8,.......................upto 60 times
let for i=34 and i=52 the if condition is satisfied then the res[1,1,1] must be 34 not 52. loop stop after i=34.

```
for(i in 1:52)
{
if(tg[i,1]>=1.5 & tg[i+1,1]>=1.5)             # tg is data file
if(tg[i+2,1]>=1.5 & tg[i+3,1]>=1.5)
if(tg[i+4,1]>=1.5 & tg[i+5,1]>=1.5)
if(tg[i+6,1]>=1.5 & tg[i+7,1]>=1.5)
if(tg[i+8,1]>=1.5)
{
res[1,1,1]<-i                             
}}}
```

Comment: Why have you tagged this as Django? None of this is valid syntax either in Django's template language or in Python.

Comment: Even if it's not Python, some indentation helps to improve readability. Of the code does not do what it should, could you please explain better, what it is, that you want to achieve? Could you please give some example data to make this reproducible and show us the expected result? Why is there a for(j ...) loop, if j does not appear in any of the following statments?

Comment: I want to determine the location from which consecutive values(minimum 9 continuous values) are greater than 1.5. Like in data set from i=34 to 42 and i=52 to 60 all values are greater than 1.5. when i run the loop it gives result as 52 which is last set of 9values. I want the loop stop when it satisfy if condition at i=34 and give res[1,1,1]=34.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a funkction out of it and return the index, something like:

```
find9 <- function(tg)
{ 
 for(i in 1:52)
  {
   if(tg[i,1]>=1.5 & tg[i+1,1]>=1.5)           
   if(tg[i+2,1]>=1.5 & tg[i+3,1]>=1.5)
   if(tg[i+4,1]>=1.5 & tg[i+5,1]>=1.5)
   if(tg[i+6,1]>=1.5 & tg[i+7,1]>=1.5)
   if(tg[i+8,1]>=1.5)
   {
    return(i)                             
}}}
res[1,1,1] <- find9(tg)
```

May be that is a nicer solution, without all the if statements:

```
>sequenceFinder <- function(vector, lengthOfSeq){

    #vector is the vector to search the sequence in
    #lengthOfSeq is the length of the sequence you want to find (in your case 9)

    for (i in 1:(length(vector)-lengthOfSeq))
    {
        mask <- vector[i:(i+lengthOfSeq-1)] >= 1.5
        if (sum(mask)==lengthOfSeq){return(i)}
    }
    return("Nothing found")
}


>set.seed(5)
>test <- rnorm(60,1.5)
>sequencefinder(test,5)
>[1]21
>sequencefinder(test,8)
[1]"Nothing found"
```